# vscode suggestion not-readable

Tags: visual-studio-code, suggestbox

helps needed!
I'm using VScode to write python.
I can see the suggestion but it's just some symbols and not readable..
If I press enter, some code will appear.. but I need help to be able to read on the scroll-box..
How can I do this please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhQ4y.jpg)

try to look at the setting.json but not sure what I need to change.
there's other question about the suggestion in VScode, but I think my case is a bit different.

This is the version I'm using:
Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: have you installed any language/translation packs? Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. Does this happen when you try with an empty [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)?

Comment: thanks starball and @HolyBlackcat when I removed everything on the settings.json, now the auto-suggestion is backed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: please post your settings.json. Let's figure out what was causing this. Are you still on the same version of VS Code? Or have you upgraded it by now? And did you try disabling extensions? What did you find when you tried disabling all your extensions?

Comment: [someone else has just had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77260452/11107541). it would really be great if you'd come back and help us figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Hi @starball Unfortunately I no longer has my old .json files to check with components is causing this errors..