# Hints are not displayed

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Win 10 ver 1.83.0
hints are not displayed, can some extension be installed? I need them to be visible

how to make sure that there were inscriptions in the place "-----"

[As I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LE9Q.png)

rebooted ? yes
Have you tried installing an extension ? yes
an extension conflict? no
(problem before installing extensions)

[One example is how it should be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY0lB.png)

Comment: Ohh, I see.  Some might call this "autocomplete" and ms might call it 'Intellisense'?  Yes, I had a lot of issues with this in Visual Studio until I 1.) upgraded to the latest version AND 2.) increased my RAM to 16 GB.  I'm pretty sure I'd get backlash for recommending 16GB RAM.   So to be sure, this is not a recommendation, just an experience.   Also, I hope I've understood your issue.  Best wishes...

Comment: @Kz2023 You were partly right, thanks for giving me the idea, I downloaded an older version, and everything worked thanks to you

Comment: 1) seems to be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77143739/11107541. 2) Please install the version you had before and copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. 3) please also show us the contents of your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)